# Using Google Breakpad HTTPUpload functionality on Linux

Tags: linux, upload, google-breakpad

I am currently using Google Breakpad in my Linux app. I built breakpad by configure&make, I am linking /src/client/linux/libbreakpad_client.a and it works fine, dump is created in case of crash.

Now I would like to also use common/linux/http_upload functions to upload dump somewhere similar way as it is done in src/tools/linux/symupload/minidump_upload but I get undefined reference to google_breakpad::HTTPUpload::SendRequest...

How to proceed? Is is not built on Linux into some library? Linking libbreakpad_client.a and libbreakpad.a does not seem to be enough. Do I need to build it somehow separately? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires src/common/linux/http_upload.cc to be included in (for example) libbreakpad_client.a, I added that line to Makefile.am to src_client_linux_libbreakpad_client_a_SOURCES section. It seems it is not built otherwise by any configure arguments or I missed it.